# Trig proof using complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Prove that if n is a positive integer, then
$\left|\frac{sin(\frac{n\theta}{2})}{sin(\frac{\theta}{2})}\right|\le n$ for $(θ ≠ 0, ±2π, ±4π, . . .)$

Any hint on how to start this question will be appreciated.

Comment: For said $\theta$, $\sin\frac{\theta}{2} =0$.

Comment: Apologies I should write not equal

Comment: Inequality would still hold: $=n$.